# facebook login php doesn't get the id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am developing a webpage in which I’m trying to login a user via PHP SDK.

I've coded my file `index.php` which is in a `facebook` folder just for a test, rooted in my domain. For any strange reason, when I connect, I get the authentication code but I try to call `$facebook -> getUser();` and it returns `0`! If I try to get the token with `$facebook-> getAccessToken();` it returns correctly as well.

Here it's the code I’ve designed to do that.

First part of the code, ask for the authentication and I redirect to a `callback.php` file in which I try to get the `userId`. Here is the code:

`Index.php`

```
<?php
require_once ('facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => '378488665495077',
    'secret' => 'XXXX',
));
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>"http://myweb.com/facebook/callback.php"));
?>
<a href="<?php echo $login_url;?>">Login with facebook</a>
```

`callback.php`

```
require_once 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => '378488665495077',
    'secret' => 'XXXXXX',
));
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$user_Id = $facebook->getUser();
$user_session = $facebook->getAccessToken();
echo $user_Id;
```

I get a url that looks like:  http://myweb.com/facebook/callback.php?code=AQjQ6.....

Does anybody know anything about this issue? To my mind it seems there must be something bad configured in http://developers.facebook.com but I don't really know what.

Answer (score 0):

On redirect, when user lands on your page the session is just being written to browser.

1. make sure you are starting session, enable cookie support.
2. a page refresh may be necessary to get information from session in browser.
3. since logout method is required, when user is redirected back to logout page, i use php sdk to clear session facebook created, then redirect user to page they logged out from.

**example:**

> // note: after facebook redirects user back to my site "to the login
>   page" i redirect that user back to the page with which they started.
>   This allows the session to be created, the passed code to be hidden
>   from url.  The downside, it takes longer, average login can be upwards
>   of 3 to 5 seconds to do full redirects.

```
session_start();
require './src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'your app id here',
  'secret' => 'your app secret',
  'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));
try { 
$user = $facebook->getUser(); 
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) { 
//error_log($e);
$user = null;
}
if($user){
   $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
}
$params = array(
  'redirect_uri' => 'Your redirect url',
);
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

$params = array(
 'next' => 'Your redirect url' 
 );
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
```